# Code works every other time in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, word-2010

The code below is programmed to retrieve data from a MS ACCESS 2010 Table and put it into a MS WORD 2010 Form b. The code works fine every time and throws NO error but opens the document and puts the data only every other time.

```
Sub Module11()
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

Dim tnum As String
Dim sname As String
Dim frst As Integer
Dim mrst As Integer
Dim sam As Integer
Dim strSQL As String

On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set appWord = New Word.Application
End If

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection



conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= D:\Database\Database.mdb"
rst.Open "tableSDR", conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic


 tnum = InputBox("Enter the Tracking Number of the Record " & _
  "you want to find:", "TRACKING NUMBER")

strSQL = "Select * from table where rst!TrackingNumber='" & tnum & "'"
'AND " _
 '   & "[rst!TrackingNumber]='" & tnum & "' "

rst.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

sam = rst!TrackingNumber

Do While Not rst.EOF
If sam <> tnum Then
    rst.MoveNext
    sam = rst!TrackingNumber

Else
     Exit Do
End If
Loop

Do While rst.EOF
MsgBox "Tracking Number Not Found! "
   Exit Sub
Loop


Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("D:\Database\Form.docx", True)


With doc
    .FormFields("model").Result = rst!Model
    .FormFields("date_submitted").Result = rst!TDate
    .FormFields("part_number").Result = rst!PartNumber
    .FormFields("sup_name").Result = rst!SupplierName
    .FormFields("part_name").Result = rst!PartName
    .FormFields("sup_location").Result = rst!SupplierLocation
    .FormFields("rev_level").Result = rst!RevisionLevel
    .FormFields("sup_contact").Result = rst!SupplierContact
    .FormFields("po_number").Result = rst!PONumber
    .FormFields("telephone_num").Result = rst!TelephoneNum
    .FormFields("quantity").Result = rst!Quantity
    .FormFields("fax_number").Result = rst!FaxNum
    .FormFields("required_date").Result = rst!RequiredDate
    .FormFields("dev_req").Result = rst!DeviationRequest
    .FormFields("dev_period").Result = rst!DeviationPeriod

        frst = rst!FirstTime
        mrst = rst!MaterialChange

        If (frst = 1) Then
             If (mrst = 1) Then
                   doc.FormFields("time").Result = " Material Change and First Time"
             ElseIf (msrt = 0) Then
                   doc.FormFields("time").Result = "First Time"
             End If
        ElseIf (frst = 0) Then
             If (mrst = 1) Then
                   doc.FormFields("time").Result = " Material Change "
             ElseIf (msrt = 0) Then
                   doc.FormFields("time").Result = "Not Applicable"
             End If
      End If


    .FormFields("cur_spec").Result = rst!CurrentSPecification
    .FormFields("prop_dev").Result = rst!ProposedDeviation
    .FormFields("reason_dev").Result = rst!ReasonForDeviation

    .FormFields("pur_sign").Result = rst!PurchaseSign
    .FormFields("pur_des").Result = rst!PurchaseAD
    .FormFields("pur_date").Result = rst!PurchaseDate
    .FormFields("pur_com").Result = rst!PurchaseComments
    .FormFields("qual_sign").Result = rst!QualitySign

    .FormFields("qual_des").Result = rst!QualityAD
    .FormFields("qual_date").Result = rst!QualityDate
    .FormFields("qual_com").Result = rst!QualityComments
    .FormFields("engg_sign").Result = rst!EnggSign

    .FormFields("engg_des").Result = rst!EnggAD
    .FormFields("engg_date").Result = rst!EnggDate
    .FormFields("engg_com").Result = rst!EnggComments

    .FormFields("manu_sign").Result = rst!ManuSign
    .FormFields("manu_des").Result = rst!ManuAD
    .FormFields("manu_date").Result = rst!ManuDate
    .FormFields("manu_com").Result = rst!ManuComments

    .FormFields("other_sign").Result = rst!OtherSign
    .FormFields("other_des").Result = rst!OtherAD
    .FormFields("other_date").Result = rst!OtherDate
    .FormFields("other_com").Result = rst!OtherComments

    .FormFields("doc_req").Result = rst!ChangeRequired
    .FormFields("pca_number").Result = rst!PCANum
    .FormFields("dis_comments").Result = rst!Comments
    .FormFields("tracking_num").Result = rst!TrackingNumber



.Visible = True

.Activate

End With

doc.ActiveDocument.SaveAs (MSQname)
doc.Quit
Set doc = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
Exit Sub

errHandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing the On Error Resume Next and see if the program will throw a warning

Comment: I've had this issue before in Access and it turned out to be a problem with not fully qualifying every call to word.

Comment: throws activex component not able to open object error

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any closure of the connection. The code falling over would cause it to close thus it would work the next time. try rs.close at then end.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10118966)

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon This is a valid attempt to answer the question. It might even be correct. If you think this is a wrong or unuseful answer, use your votes.

Comment: I think you will find that my answer is in most cases the solution to ADO and other connection problems. As pointed out a valid attempt to answer the question. There is indeed no attempt to close the open connection. which would result in intermittent performance.